# How do you make a table row scroll into view when the table is in a scrollable div with jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

With a div that scrolls:

```
<div id="PVwindow" style="overflow: scroll; max-width:800px; max-height:230px; float:left;">
```

how do I get a row to be scrolled into view like:

```
<table id="PVtable"><tbody><tr>.....</tr>.....<tr id="scrollToViewP" style="background-color: #FFFF99;"><td>xxxx</td></tr></tbody></table>
```

Here is the non-working code (it scrolls but out of view):

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
         if ($("#scrollToViewP:not(:visible)")) {
            $("#PVwindow").animate({
                  scrollTop: $("#scrollToViewP").offset().top
                 }, 1000);
                }
    });
```

Here is a [jsfiddle working example that scrolls to the bottom](https://jsfiddle.net/mattman85208/sh5cj30z/3/)

Comment: Off topic. This question does not appear to be about programming within the scope defined in the help center.

Comment: I've added the code. Is that what is necessary to make it 'on topic'?

Comment: Make a jsfiddle producing your problem. Also, `if ($(...)) {` doesn't make sense, because jquery object is always truthy.

Comment: Added a jsfiddle that is functional but doesn't scroll properly. it is scrolling to the bottom and the subject row is above the visible area.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a solution that works most of the time (Like 80%), sometimes it scrolls the whole window as well as the div.

```
<script>
$( document ).ready(function() {

    var element = document.getElementById("scrollToViewP");
    element.scrollIntoView({block: "end", behavior: "smooth"});

});
```

I'm still hopeful someone will come along and improve this.
(Works in FireFox and IE 11)

Comment: Since the whole window scrolls sometimes I've made this small change and improved this script a lot.

    $( document ).ready(function() {   
    var element = document.getElementById("scrollToViewP");
    element.scrollIntoView({block: "end", behavior: "smooth"});
    var xcoord = 0;
    var ycoord = 0;
    window.scrollTo(xcoord, ycoord);
    });
`code`